# Faster data aggregation algorithms for nested objects

Tags: python

I am having some trouble learning about new methods of flattening/aggregating nested object data in python. My current implementation is rather slow, and I want to know some approaches to speed up processing. Consider that I have a dataset of donations defined as:

```
donations = [
  {
    "amount": 100,
    "organization": {
      "name": "Org 1",
      "total_budget": 8000,
      "states": [
        {
          "name": "Maine",
          "code": "ME"
        },
        {
          "name": "Massachusetts",
          "code": "MA"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "amount": 5000,
    "organization": {
      "name": "Org 2",
      "total_budget": 10000,
      "states": [
        {
          "name": "Massachusetts",
          "code": "MA"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "amount": 5000,
    "organization": {
      "name": "Org 1",
      "total_budget": 8000,
      "states": [
        {
          "name": "Maine",
          "code": "ME"
        },
        {
          "name": "Massachusetts",
          "code": "MA"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

The relationship of these objects is such that a donation is related to a single organization, and an organization can be related to one or more states.

I additionally can get just the organization dataset as:

```
organizations = [
  {
    "name": "Org 1",
    "total_budget": 8000,
    "states": [
      {
        "name": "Maine",
        "code": "ME"
      },
      {
        "name": "Massachusetts",
        "code": "MA"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Org 2",
    "total_budget": 10000,
    "states": [
      {
        "name": "Massachusetts",
        "code": "MA"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The output I am looking to achieve is an aggregation, by state, of the total donations and total budget, where the donation amounts and the organization's total budget is evenly distributed among all states it is associated with. Example for the above dataset:

```
results = {
  "ME": {
    "name": "Maine",
    "total_donations": 2550
    "total_budget": 4000
  },
  "MA": {
    "name": "Massachusetts",
    "total_donations": 7550
    "total_budget": 14000
  }
}
```

What I have tried so far is to use for loops to iterate through each donation and organization, and sort them into a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def get_stats():
  return { "total_donations": 0, "total_budget": 0, "name": "" }

results = defaultdict(get_stats)

for donation in donations:
  for state in donation["organization"]["states"]
    results[state["code"]]["total_donations"] += donation["amount"]/len(donation["organization"]["states"])

for organization in organizations:
  for state in organization["states"]:
    results[state["code"]]["total_budget"] += organization["total_budget"]/len(organization["states"])
    results[state["code"]]["name"] = state["state"]
```

I was thinking about using map/reduce here, but I didn't get the sense that those would improve performance. Any advice here would be super appreciated.

Comment: if the dataset is big and the performance is your big concern, probably you should consider to use `Pandas`.

Comment: I was looking at a lot of examples of `pandas`, but I couldn't figure out how to match up these datasets there. Any advice for a sample implementation?

Comment: How slow is the current code? Any obvious bottleneck?

Comment: The first for loop (donations) takes ~20 seconds, the second (organizations) takes ~5 seconds

Comment: @JasperSardonicus For how many objects in the list? How doe these timings scale for more objects?

Comment: This is for 151 donations and 103 organizations

Comment: Correction, the first loop is about 9 seconds, not 20